# How to restart async function in bloc while it's working?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart, dart-stream

There is a simple bloc, which uses rxdart controller. It does nothing but streaming srings in general. There is a logic in it to start reading again.

```
class ReaderBloc {
  bool started = false;
  final _publishStream = PublishSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get publishStream => _publishStream.stream;

  startReading() async {
    List<String> lines = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];

    for (String l in lines) {
      if (started) {
        started = false;
        _publishStream.done;
        break;
      }
      _publishStream.add(l);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _publishStream.close();
  }
}
```

and a view which simply receive and display those strings from bloc logic

```
class Reader extends StatefulWidget {
  const Reader({super.key});
  @override
  State<Reader> createState() => _ReaderState();
}

class _ReaderState extends State<Reader> {
  late ReaderBloc readerBloc;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    readerBloc = Provider.of<ReaderBloc>(context);

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.refresh,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // seems this part doesn't work
                readerBloc.started = true;
                readerBloc.startReading();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Scaffold(body: tabBody(readerBloc.publishStream)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  tabBody(Stream<String> stream) {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return Text(
          snapshot.data.toString(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

before we go on Reader route we execute the following, i.e. nothing special but getting our bloc, start reading async function and finally go to the Reader route

```
Provider.of<ReaderBloc>(context, listen: false).startReading();
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Reader()));
```

The wrong part — there is a refresh button in Reader view to start reading again from the beginning, but it does not work as expected, i.e. it does not stop current reading and does not start new reading. Wherein I get no errors.

What I missed with this is that it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Where is the part of your code that is supposed to stop the reading?

Comment: @Abion47 see the Reader's `// seems this part doesn't work` comment and the corresponding condition in bloc with `break` keyword.

Comment: I see nothing in that code that would do anything to stop the reading that's in progress. I think the misunderstanding comes from what calling an async method actually does. Recalling the same method doesn't stop the action that calling it previously started. It's like pushing a boulder down a hill. You can push another boulder down the hill, but that's not going to stop the boulder that's already on its way down. All that will do is make it so now you have two boulders rolling down the hill.

Comment: @Abion47 did you notice the `started` flag? doesn't the async function already see the value of the changed flag when we click the refresh button?

Comment: No, because you immediately call `startReading` after that, and _that_ call will see that `started == true` and will break long before the existing operation will make that check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these changes solved the problem

in view:

```
onPressed: () {
    readerBloc.started = true;
},
```

in bloc:

```
if (started) {
    started = !started;
    startReading();
    break;
}
```